# Is there any way to use hidden html field to read barcode?

Tags: python, html, django, barcode, hidden

I'm trying to find a way to hide input field used to read barcode but I don't know if it's possible. I'm using Python/Django framework.

Everything works fine with TextInput widget : I set autofocus on the field, submit on change and put a "start reading" button to set focus in case user remove it. When I replace by HiddenInput, it doesn't work anymore. I think focus is not relevant with hidden input, am I right ?

Someone has an idea ? If not, I will let it displayed...

Thx

Comment: Have you tried just hiding the text input using opacity: 0? Would that solve your problem or do you specifically need a hidden input field (as in input type="hidden")?

Comment: or just put it in an overflow:hidden and move the input out of sight ... I dont think hiddeninputs allow for user input period ... so I dont think a barcode scanner will work (nor a keyboard which is how a barcode scanner enumerates)

Comment: opacity:0 or overflow:hidden are good solutions I think. I will try. thx.